# PHP cleaner way to show all keys if array is empty

Tags: php

Looking for a cleaner way to accomplish the following: If the `$selected = array();` is empty... then `in_array($key, $key);` the `in_array()` will work fine as is, but if the array is empty I would like to show all keys.

can't seem to figure out a simple logic to this?

```
$selected = array(5,9,11,12);

// Loop through Array
  foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
        echo $value["name"] . "<br>"; 
            $length = count($value["color"]);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                if($value['time'][$i] != "") {
                echo "<span style=" . $value["color"][$i] . ">" . $value["time"][$i] . "</span><br>"; 
                }
            }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the content in `$json` variable?

Comment: `if (in_array($key, $selected) || empty($selected))` - is that what you mean?

Comment: It's not the Json array I'm referring too. It's the $select - however the json array has 0-30 keys sometimes more

Comment: Yes it is .....

Comment: perfact, thanks, I knew it was something simple, just couldn't recall the logic